# OverrideingPendingTransition android implementation

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, transition, overridependingtransition

I am writing some code to override default enter and exit animations for `Activity`.

I am using **OverridePendingTransition** to achieve this task
Here I am doing transition from Activity1 to Activity2.

What I want is that, Activity1 should move from right to left and Activity2 should stay appeared behind this without any animation.

How can I achieve that?

Here I have tried putting **0** for entering Animation, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the anim functions by moving from Activty1 to Activity2.

```
public class AnimUtils {
/*Right to Left Slide Animation*/
public static void rightToLeftAnimation(Activity activity) {
    activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
}
/*Left to Right*/
public static void leftToRightAnimation(Activity activity) {
    activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}}
```

Create a res directory name as anim. And put the .xml files in that directory.

Here is the slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
<alpha
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

The slide_out_left.xml anim

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" />
<alpha
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

And the slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
<alpha
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

Also slide_out_right.xml, keep in mind you can change the animation as your choice by shifting the places of the animation in the code above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%" />
<alpha
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans. But I want to animate exit activity only. Entering Activity should stay without any animation

Comment: In the above example, you can change the variation of the animation and activities behind and above. Just do hit and trail.